# Setting UIImageView.image binded by UIImageView.bnd_image to Observable<UIImage> object is not observed

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using [Swift Bond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond) for data binding. I am trying to bind a `UIImageView`'s image variable in my ViewController to an `Observable` variable in my ViewModel to observe when the image is set. Having done the following approach, when I set the `UIImageView`'s `image` from the `ViewController`, my `Observable` variable's `observeNew()` method is not called. I would expect it to be called. I have some other data bindings and they work. I've included one in the code snippet.

**ViewController**

```
class PostViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  var viewModel: PostViewModel!
  var caption: UITextField!
  var postImageView: UIImageView!

  init() {
    viewModel = PostViewModel()
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() { 
    -- view setup omitted --
    view.addSubview(caption)
    view.addSubview(postImageView)

    createBindings()
  }

  private func createBindings() {
   -- other data bindings omitted --
   caption.bnd_text.bindTo(viewModel.caption)
   postImageView.bnd_image.bindTo(viewModel.postPhoto)
  }

  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    // I would expect setting the image here would trigger the binding and observeNew() would be called
    postImageView.image = image
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class PostViewModel {
  let caption   = Observable<String?>("")
  let postPhoto = Observable<UIImage?>(nil)

  init() {
    caption.observeNew({ text in
      // Prints text when caption: UITextField is edited
      print(text)
    })

    postPhoto.observeNew({ image in
      // Doesn't print statement when postImageView: UIImageView is set 
      print("Post received a new image")
    })
  }
}
```

I've tried many different ways to observe any change to the UIImageView, but none are observed:

- reversing the binding to `viewModel.postPhoto.bindTo(postImageView.bnd_image)` and changing `viewModel.postPhoto`'s value
- trying bidirectionally `viewModel.postPhoto.bidirectionalBindTo(postImageView.bnd_image)`

I've read the [Bond Demo app](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond-Demo-App/blob/f5b912e416c6894a85936edb71ddb096155345cb/BondDemo/ListViewController.swift#L37) where they do the viewModel to UIImageView bind

I've checked out [Unit tests](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond/blob/master/BondTests/UIImageViewTests.swift) where they test the UIImageView bond

I've read through a few tutorials including [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/123108/bond-tutorial)

I've also tried other data bindings on the `UIImageView` object's `image` variable such as `bnd_backgroundColor` and changing the background color upon an action just to see if the `Observable` is called, but it isn't, so I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is...

I just want to know when the `UIImageView`'s image is changed.

Comment: Reversing the binding to `viewModel.postPhoto.bindTo(postImageView.bnd_image)` and setting `viewModel.postPhoto = image` was actually what I needed. It updates the `UIImageView` with the `UIImage` and triggers the `Observable`. I'm not sure what happened the first time I tried this reversal of the bindings. I would still like to know why my first approach doesn't trigger the `Observable`